# CSS parameters for web page layout

Tags: css, layout

I am really a beginner in making web pages. I read tons of tutorials and I made quite a progress I think. But I am stuck on one simple problem. I want to make a simple webpage with this layout:
http://i49.tinypic.com/1r54l4.jpg

I have a body with background. I want this background to be visible above and under the png logo. Then I have canvas with menu on the left side with the same color background. And then the footer with a little margin again. The code looks like this:

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding-top: 10px;
background-image: url('pics/background.png');
background-repeat: repeat; 
}

#wrapper {
width:1200px;
height:100%;
margin-left:12%;
}

#content {
background: rgba(255, 251, 208, 0.9);
height:100%;
margin-top:10px;
}

#menu {
width:16%;
float:left;
}

#canvas {
width:84%;
float:right;
}
```

With this I get just the webpage without the background color. And for example Firebug shows that the height of wrapper or content ends just above the canvas.
I tried tens of different settings but something was wrong every time.

Comment: Try this : 
html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

Comment: Well this is working but then I get superlong web page with the content of the same height as is the height of body even though the real content inside is just in cca one third only. I was wondering how to make an universal layout which would be adapting to the content of the canvas. For me it seems like the menu and canvas isn't somehow respecting that it is inside the content div. Thanks for help..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a clearfix class ( http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ ) on the wrapper, from what I can see all wrapper inner elements are floating